# Can observable collection be passed as ref parameter?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, observablecollection

Can an observable collection be passed as a reference parameter?

I am getting an error that this can't be passed as a reference parameter.

This is the exact error message I am getting:

*"A property of indexer may not be passed as an out or ref parameter".*

Comment: Hey man, you'll have to do a little more legwork if you want help.  We'll need simple code that still shows the error, the error message you're getting, whether it's a run-time or compile-time error, and all that.  Could you edit your post to include those?

Comment: In .NET you don't need to do this for anything other than structs/value types.  All types that aren't primitive (reference types) are passed by ref automatically, and most of the time if you're passing value types by ref or out your design probably needs work.

Comment: @Will: not exactly. In C#, no types are passed by ref automatically. Think of `Dictionary<string, string>.TryGetValue("blah", out x);` Even though string is a reference type, `Dictionary<string, string>.TryGetValue("blah", x);` does not work.

Comment: @Martin I wasn't exactly clear.  I have found that lots of ... new programmers, let's call them, think that the only way to pass a reference type so that it isn't passed by value is to send it as a ref.  Also, I left out immutable types, yes.  And the anti-pattern where you wish to return multiple values from a method call and so have to pass all your variables as ref (or out, depending on the method) etc etc etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can pass an `ObservableCollection` by reference. However, you can't pass `this` by reference for any class. (You can for a struct, but please don't.)

If you're having trouble passing a normal variable by reference, please post some code.

EDIT: I've just seen your edit... and the compiler error message is fairly clear. You can't pass properties or indexers by reference. So you can't do:

```
Foo(ref x.SomeProperty);
```

but you can do:

```
var tmp = x.SomeProperty;
Foo(ref tmp);
x.SomeProperty = tmp;
```

Comment: my ObservableCollection  is of type class.

Comment: @Anish: See my edited answer. Your question wasn't clear before - it's clearer now, so hopefully my answer will be of more use. If not, please post your actual code rather than just the error message.